# Definine a function which accepts either functions or constants as arguments

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns

I wish to define a function, which accepts either functions or constants as arguments. I tried

```
g[t_, y_] := Module[{}, t[y]]
```

which simply evaluates some function `t` at `y`.

Now if I run

```
t[x_] = 300
g[t, y]
```

the module `g` simply returns 300. However if I run

```
g[300, y]
```

it returns:

```
300[y]
```

How do I define `g` in such a way that it accepts either functions or constants as arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edited

I'm uncomfortable with the idea of writing a function with the kind of special behavior you propose, but if I had to, I would implement it this way.

```
g[x_?NumericQ, y_] := x
g[t_, y_] := t[y]
```

Then

```
Clear[t]; t[x_] = 300; g[t, y]
```

> `300`

```
Clear[h]; h[x_] := 3 x; g[h, y]
```

> `3 y`

```
g[300, y]
```

> `300`

```
g[#^2 &, y]
```

> `y^2`

Comment: +1, but I think in this case less might even be more. If you don't restrict the first pattern to `_Symbol | _Function` it will also work for other function like arguments like e.g. `CompiledFunction`, `InterpolatingFunction`, `ParametricFunction`, `FittedModel`...

Comment: @AlbertRetey. You're right, and I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SetAttributes[g, Orderless]
g[t_Symbol, y_] := Module[{}, t[y]]

g[t, 200]
```

> t[200]

```
g[300, y]
```

> y[300]

```
t[x_] := 300
g[300, t]
```

> 300

```
g[t, 200]
```

> 300